# float/ fixed sidebar overalapping bottom divs/footers

Tags: html, css

I have a development page that has a sidebar called 'blog-sidebar'. I wish to have this float up and down as you scroll but stop at the end of the container of the page. Currently it scrolls all the way down to the bottom footer of the page overallping over some of the bottom divs and footer. 
How can I get it to only scroll up and down within that section of the page.

Thanks

http://pmg.dekastudiotest.net.au/communication.html

```css
/* BLOG */
.blog{ width:100%; float:left; padding:50px 0; overflow: hidden;}
.blog *{-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease; transition: all 0.3s ease;}
.blog .blog-post{ width:100%; float:left; padding-right:20px; margin-bottom:50px;}
.blog figure{ width:100%;float:left; margin-bottom:20px; position:relative; background:#febd0e;}
.blog figure img{ width:100%; float:left;}
.blog figure:hover img{ opacity:0.7;}
.blog h3{ display:block; margin-top:0; color:#febd0e;}
.blog small{ display:block; margin-bottom:10px; color:#98989a; font-weight:700;}
.blog .border{ width:38px; height:3px; display:inline-block; margin-bottom:30px; background:#febd0e;}
.blog .link {font-size:18px; font-weight:700; border-bottom:3px solid #febd0e; padding-bottom:6px; color:#febd0e;}
.blog .link:hover{ text-decoration:none;}
.blog .pagination{ width:100%; float:left;}
.blog .pagination>li{ float:left;}
.blog .pagination>li a{ float:left; border:1px dotted #ccc; font-weight:700; font-size:12px; padding:6px 22px; color:#2f2e33; border-radius:0 !important;}
.blog .pagination>.active>a, .pagination>.active>a:focus, .pagination>.active>a:hover, .pagination>.active>span, .pagination>.active>span:focus, .pagination>.active>span:hover{ background:#febd0e; color:#fff;}




/* SIDEBAR */
.blog-sidebar{ width:300px; padding-left:30px; position:fixed; }
.blog-sidebar .widgets{ width:100%; float:left; margin-bottom:40px;}
.blog-sidebar .social-media{ width:100%; float:left;}
.blog-sidebar .social-media ul{ width:100%; float:left;}
.blog-sidebar .social-media ul li{ width:34px; height:34px; line-height:34px; float:left; text-align:center; background:red; margin-right:4px;}
.blog-sidebar .social-media ul li a{ display:inline-block; font-size:17px; color:#fff;}
.blog-sidebar .social-media ul li.facebook{ background:#3b5999;}
.blog-sidebar .social-media ul li.twitter{ background:#00bcf8;}
.blog-sidebar .social-media ul li.googleplus{ background:#d3492d;}
.blog-sidebar .social-media ul li.instagram{ background:#5989b9;}
.blog-sidebar .social-media ul li.pinterest{ background:#f63234;}
.blog-sidebar .social-media ul li.youtube{ background:#fe0000;}
.blog-sidebar .search{ width:100%; float:left;}
.blog-sidebar .search form{ width:100%; float:left;}
.blog-sidebar .search form input[type="text"]{ width:80%; float:left;}
.blog-sidebar .search form button[type="submit"]{ width:20%;  padding:0; text-align:center; float:left; background:#febd0e; color:#fff; margin-left:-3px;}
.blog-sidebar .tags{ width:100%; float:left;}
.blog-sidebar .tags a{ float:left; padding-bottom:5px; border-bottom:2px solid #eee; font-size:12px; color:#999; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px;}
.blog-sidebar .tags a:hover{text-decoration:none; color:#00cadf;}
.blog-sidebar .categories{ width:100%; float:left;}
.blog-sidebar .categories ul{ width:100%; float:left;}
.blog-sidebar .categories ul li{ width:100%; float:left; margin:4px 0;}
.blog-sidebar .categories ul li a{ float:left; color:#003D98; font-weight:500;}
.blog-sidebar .categories ul li a:hover{color:#00cadf;}
.blog-sidebar .gallery-thumbs{ width:100%; float:left; margin-left:-5px; margin-right:-5px;}
.blog-sidebar .gallery-thumbs a{ width:33.33333%; float:left; padding:5px;}
.blog-sidebar .gallery-thumbs a img{ width:100%; float:left;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Print Media - Communication</title>
<meta name="author" content="Themezinho">
<meta name="description" content="SREATIVE | Digital Agency HTML Template">
<meta name="keywords" content="html, template, carousel, theme, themezinho, agency, html5">

<!-- SOCIAL MEDIA META -->
<meta property="og:description" content="SREATIVE | Digital Agency">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.acrocapoeira.com/sreative/preview.png">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SREATIVE">
<meta property="og:title" content="SREATIVE">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.acrocapoeira.com/sreative">

<!-- TWITTER META -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@SREATIVE">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SREATIVE">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="SREATIVE">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="SREATIVE | Digital Agency">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.acrocapoeira.com/sreative/preview.png">

<!-- FAVICON FILES -->
<link href="ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144">
<link href="ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114">
<link href="ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72">
<link href="ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed">
<link href="ico/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon">

<!-- CSS FILES -->
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/settings.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="loading yellow-bg">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="inner"> <img src="images/light_logo.png" alt="Image">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- end inner --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end table --> 
</div>
<!-- end loading -->
<div class="transition-overlay yellow-bg"></div>
<!-- end transition-overlay -->
<div class="side-menu"> <span class="side-menu-close"><i class="ion-android-close"></i></span>
  <h4>QUICK CONTACT</h4>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="NAME">
    <input type="text" placeholder="E-MAIL ADDRESS">
    <input type="text" placeholder="SUBJECT">
    <textarea placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE"></textarea>
    <button type="button">SEND MESSAGE</button>
  </form>
  <ul>
    <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li class="googleplus"><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-googleplus"></i></a></li>
    <li class="instagram"><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li class="pinterest"><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-pinterest"></i></a></li>
    <li class="youtube"><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-youtube"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<header class="yellow-bg int-header" style="background:#36BAEA">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="nav" >
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle toggle-menu menu-left push-body" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/light_logo.png" alt="Image"></a> </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="index.html" class="transition">HOME</a></li>
           <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="works-masonry.html" class="transition">PRINT SERVICES</a></li>
              <li><a href="works-nonspaced.html" class="transition">COMMUNICATIONS</a></li>
              <li><a href="works-spaced.html" class="transition">DIGITAL MEDIA</a></li>
                     <li><a href="works-spaced.html" class="transition">SMART WORKS</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
             <li><a href="smartworks.html" class="transition">ENVIRONMENT</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html" class="transition">NEWS</a></li>
                     <li><a href="about-us.html" class="transition">ABOUT US</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html" class="transition">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html" class="transition">LOG IN</a></li>
          
          
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end navbar-collapse --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end container --> 
  </nav>

  <!-- end nav -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h2 class="title">COMMUNICATIONS</h2>
        <h5 class="sub-title">We provide a range of communication services tailored to your needs.</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="blog">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 wow fadeInUp">
        <div class="blog-post">
       
          <h2>Communication Boards</h2>
           <img src="images/cleanglass.png" alt="Image" style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 20px;">
          <span class="border"></span>
          <p>Our Communication & Journey Boards offer a functional and aesthetically pleasing way to capture key information and reinforce results. The unique construction allows providers to change the poster incorporated underneath the acrylic writing surfaces</p>
          <p> Consisting of a pre-printed poster and clear acrylic face that acts as a dry-erase surface, the poster allows hospitals and aged care facilities to personalise critical information by ward or division and can be changed easily to accommodate updated information. This eliminates the need to dispose of pre-printed white boards as any changes occur.</p>
          <blockquote> Customise your boards:  Our boards come in a range of sizes from A5 up to A1 plus. We can customise any size for your specific requirements. We can also design any posters you like. Just ask us! </blockquote>
           <img src="images/boards1.png" alt="Image" style="width: 60%; padding-bottom: 20px;"><br>
           <div class="content-box">
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" style="display: inline-block;
    background: #003D98;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:16px;
    padding: 15px 30px;" href="https://dekastudio.wufoo.com/forms/z1rn9pef1ipkwq4/">Enquire About This Product</a>

</div>
  
</div>

          <p> <strong>Consider the benefits</strong></p>

          <li> Aesthetics: Clean Modern Look</li>
          <li> Legible: Clear, Non Ghoshting Attributes </li>
          <li> Safe: Durable Design</li>
          <li> Functionaly: Quick Content and Design Flexibility </li>
          <li> Cost Effective: Smart, Long-Term Financial Investment</li>
          <br>
          <p> <strong>Display a range of information including:</strong></p>
          <li> Pain and Care Charts </li>
          <li> Safety Information </li>
          <li> Saff on Call</li>
          <li> Rights and Responsibilities </li>
          <li> Operating Procedures</li>
          <li> Daily Duties </li>

        
        <!-- end blog-post --> 
      </div>
      <!-- end col-8 -->
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <aside class="blog-sidebar">
          <div class="widgets social-media wow fadeInUp">
            <h4>ABOUT PMG</h4>
            <p>Print Media Group is a leading corporate print specialist. A proudly 100% Australian owned family business, we employ more than 230 staff nationally in manufacturing and specialised print solutions.</p>
          </div>
          <!-- end text-content -->
          <div class="widgets tags wow fadeInUp">
            <h4>Other Communication Services</h4>
            <a href="#">Journey Boards</a> <a href="#">Kitting – Care Pack, Maternity Pack, Welcome Packs</a> <a href="#">Marketing Products</a> <a href="#">Banners</a> <a href="#">Staff Awards / Certificates</a> <a href="#">Direct Mail</a>
          <!-- end tags -->
          <div class="widgets categories wow fadeInUp">
            <h4>OUR SERVICES</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Print Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Communications</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Digital Media</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Smart Works</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- end categories -->
         
          <!-- end social-media --> 
        </aside>
      </div>
      </div>

      <!-- end col-4 --> 
    
    
  
  <!-- end container --> 
</section>
<!-- end blog -->
<section class="quote">
  <div class="container wow fadeInUp">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="content-box">
          <h3>CONTACT US <strong>TODAY</strong></h3>
          <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem seqi nesciunt. Neque poro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit.</p>
          <a href="contact.html">ENQUIRE NOW</a> </div>
        <!-- end content-box --> 
      </div>
      <!-- end col-12 --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end row --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end container --> 
</section>
<!-- end quote -->
<section class="contact">
  <div class="container wow fadeInUp">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h2>CONTACT</h2>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-12 -->
     
  <div class="col-md-3">
        <figure><img src="images/icon5.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>LOCATION</dt>
          <dd>Australia Wide Locations</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-3 -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <figure><img src="images/icon6.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>PHONE</dt>
          <dd>+03 8761 4800 - National Reception</dd>

        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-3 -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <figure><img src="images/icon7.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>E-MAIL</dt>
      
          <dd>healthcare@pmg.com.au</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-3 -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <figure><img src="images/icon8.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>Working hours</dt>
          <dd></dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-3 --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end row --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end container --> 
</section>
<!-- end contact -->
<footer>
  <div class="container wow fadeInUp">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="images/light_logo.png" alt="Image" style="width: 200px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
       <p>Print Media Group is a leading corporate print specialist.
A proudly 100% Australian owned family business, we employ more than 
230 staff nationally in manufacturing and specialised print solutions.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-4 -->
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>PHOTO GALLERY</h4>
        <ul class="gallery">
          <li>
            <figure><img src="images/gallery1.jpg" alt="Image">
              <figcaption><a href="images/ungcweb.jpg" class="fancybox"><i class="ion-android-expand"></i></a></figcaption>
            </figure>
          </li>
          <li>
            <figure><img src="images/gallery2.jpg" alt="Image">
              <figcaption><a href="images/fscsmall1.jpg" class="fancybox"><i class="ion-android-expand"></i></a></figcaption>
            </figure>
          </li>
          <li>
            <figure><img src="images/gallery3.jpg" alt="Image">
              <figcaption><a href="images/carbonneutrallogo.jpg" class="fancybox"><i class="ion-android-expand"></i></a></figcaption>
            </figure>
          </li>
          <li>
           
        </ul>
        <!-- end gallery --> 
      </div>
      <!-- end col-4 -->
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>NEWSLETTER</h4>
        <p>Find out about new and exciting products and information regarding Print Media Group HealthCare.</p>
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Your e-mail">
          <button type="submit">SUBSCRIBE</button>
        </form>
        <small>* I promise, we won’t spam you!</small> </div>
      <!-- end col-4 --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end row --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end container --> 
</footer>
<!-- end footer -->
<section class="sub-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <h6>Copyright © 2015 ,Print Media Group</h6>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-6 -->
 <a href="http://www.dekastudio.com">
 <img src="images/powerdeka.png"  data-src-retina="images/powerdeka.png" width="150"  class="" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-6 --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end row --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end container --> 
</section>
<!-- end sub-footer --> 

<!-- JS FILES --> 
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
 $(window).load(function(){
  $(".loading .table .inner").addClass("fade");
  $('.loading').delay(2000).addClass("fade-out"); 
 });
})(jQuery)
</script> 
<script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/isotope.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/masonry.js"></script> 
<script src="js/wow.js"></script> 
<script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script> <script src="js/jquery.stellar.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src='js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js' type='text/javascript' ></script> 
<script src='js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js' type='text/javascript' ></script> 
<script src='js/settings.js' type='text/javascript' ></script> 
<script src='js/scripts.js' type='text/javascript' ></script>
<script src='js/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js' type='text/javascript' ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to check out [Semantic Ui's Sticky Module](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky.html) - it will do exactly what you are asking and requires you not to have to code it.

Comment: that seems like a more complicated approach...